# How do I do as many tricks as possible in a row?

Tags: jet-set-radio

I'm playing the tutorial, and got stuck at the "*Do 10 tricks in a row*" part. I've tried hard and long, but I seem to be unable to do 10 tricks in a row.

**How do I do 10 tricks in a row in the tutorial level? Or: how do I do as many tricks as possible in a row, in general?**

Note: I'm playing Jet Set Radio HD on the PC, and am playing with the keyboard.

[image: Do 10 tricks in a row]

Comment: Jet Set Radio's tutorial is surprisingly brutal. (Relevant video: [Jet Set Radio - World's Hardest Achievements - Training Wheels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XguW7PGPo_E))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick to this challenge (and the ones that follow [30, and 50]), is grinding. You will continually rack up tricks as you grind.

The easiest way to do this in the tutorial is to follow a (somewhat) simple path of rails and walls for you to grind and ride, respectively. You can, with practice, make a continuous loop of the map, without ever really leaving a rail of one type or another. The following YouTube video details the path perfectly. It does take a bit of practice, though. It took me a good fifteen to twenty minutes of completely failing before I finally managed to get it right.